# AWK filter data by characters

Tags: bash, awk

A data set like below:

```
07021201180934221NJL B2018   12X 15253                                                                                                               030C       000000.299
07021201180934231NSL B2018   12X 15253                                                                                                               030C        00000.014
07021201180941061NNL B2018                                                                                                                           030C       000000.288
```

Questions are:

1. The characters in the first string "120118" means date "ddmmyy", how could I filter rows according to date characters using awk?
2. The characters in first string "NJL" or "NSL" or "NNL" means data type, what awk command to filter lines according to those three characters?
3. The third column could be some description like "12X 15253" or empty, how could I filter data out if the column is empty?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I found `substr($0, start, length)` helpful to filter the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this script has all the conditions

```
$ awk 'substr($1,5,6)==120118 && substr($1,length($1)-2)=="NNL" && $3$4==""' file
```

Comment: There may or may not be a space between "$3" "$4". The value could be "12X 15253" or "othertext" in that position. I didn't explain the data format clearly. I found substr($0, start, length) helpful in this case.

Comment: if there is no space, how do you know there are two fields.  Regardless, this check should work.